# Angular issue with multiple inputs in form - data in inputs are duplicated

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form. So when I have only just one form and put data then everything is okay. But when I click 'add new item' and there are many inputs the data looks the same. Everything is duplicated. Maybe someone can help me? Service and data everything is fine the only problem is with multiple inputs.
Here's html:

```html
    <form method="POST" [formGroup]="addInvoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="addData()">
      <div class="formularz" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <mat-form-field >
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name"   maxlength="30" minlength="3" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="addInvoiceF['name'].errors && addInvoiceF['name'].errors['required']">Name is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Count</mat-label>
          <input type="number"  formControlName="count" matInput  maxlength="100" minlength="1">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field >
          <mat-label>Price</mat-label>
          <input type="number" matInput formControlName="price"  maxlength="1000000" minlength="1" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="addInvoiceF['price'].errors && addInvoiceF['price'].errors['required']">Price is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" class="delete" matTooltip="Remove item" (click)="deleteForm(item)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="add-new">
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button color="primary" class="add" matTooltip="Add new item" (click)="addForm()">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          Add new item
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="add">
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" class="myButton" id="add_data_button">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and typescript:

```js
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { PagesService } from '../pages.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-new-invoice',
      templateUrl: './new-invoice.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./new-invoice.component.css']
    })
    export class NewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
    
      addInvoiceForm!: FormGroup;
      get addInvoiceF() { return this.addInvoiceForm.controls; }
    
      items: any[] = [
        { form: new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            count: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            price: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
          })
        }
      ];
    
      formRows: any[] = [{ name: '', count: 1, price: '' }];
    
      constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private pagesService: PagesService,
        private router: Router
      ) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
          for (let key in localStorage) {
            if (key.includes('formRows')) {
              localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.addInvoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          count: ['', ],
          price: ['', Validators.required],
        });
      }
    
      addFormRow() {
        this.formRows.push({ name: '', count: 1, price: '' });
      }
    
      addForm() {
        const newForm = {
          form: new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            count: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            price: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
          })
        };
        this.items.push(newForm);
      }
    
      deleteForm(item: any) {
        const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    
      addData() {
    if (this.addInvoiceForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    
    const formRows = this.items.map(item => ({
      name: this.addInvoiceF['name'].value || '',
      count: this.addInvoiceF['count'].value || '',
      price: this.addInvoiceF['price'].value || '' 
    }));
    
    this.pagesService.setFormData(formRows);
    
    console.log(formRows);
    
    this.router.navigate(['/preview-invoice']);
  }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 FormGroup in your HTML code. You should do something like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let item from items; let index">
    <form [FormGroup]="getFormGroup(index)">

        <mat-form-field >
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name"   maxlength="30" minlength="3" required>
        </mat-form-field>

        <!-- Other Inputs here -->
    </form>
</div>

<button (click)="submitAll()"> submit Button </button>
```

and with

```
    getFormGroup(index:number){
        return items[index]; // maybe index -1 if it begin with 1
    }

    submitAll(){
        let data:any[];

        this.items.forEach(item => {
            data.push({
                 name : item.get('name').value,
                 count : item.get('count').value,
                 price : item.get('price').value,
                 })
        })

        // Do something with data

    }
```

The problem in your code is that you only have 1 FormGroup for all the item in items object; that's why with only 1 item it work but not with 2 + item.

Comment: Too many errors with this solution.

Comment: addData() {
    if (this.addInvoiceForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const formRows = this.items.map(item => ({
      name: item.form.value.name || '',
      count: item.form.value.count || '',
      price: item.form.value.price || '' 
    }));
    
    formRows.push({
      name: this.addInvoiceF['name'].value || '',
      count: this.addInvoiceF['count'].value || '',
      price: this.addInvoiceF['price'].value || '' 
    });
    this.pagesService.setFormData(formRows);
    console.log(formRows); 
    this.router.navigate(['/preview-invoice']);
  }

Comment: I changed the code but now there's ony data from added inputs not from the 'main ' input

Comment: For the last problem , you should add 'main' inputs in Items